# What is the bitwise negation for an integer?

Tags: python-3.x, bitwise-operators

I have homework assignment with a piece to compute the bitwise negation of integer value. It say 512 go into -513.

I have a solution that does `x = 512 y = 512*(-1)+(-1)`.

Is that correct way?

Answer (score 0):

This property is based on the way negative number are represented in two's complement. To represent a negative number $A$ on *n* bits, one uses the complement of |*A*| to 2<sup>*n*</sup>, i.e. the number 2<sup>*n*</sup>-|*A*|

It is easy to see that *A*+~*A*=111...11 as bits in the addition will always be 0 and 1 and 111...111 is the number just before 2<sup>*n*</sup>, or 2<sup>*n*</sup>-1.

As -|*A*| is coded by 2<sup>*n*</sup>-|*A*|, and *A* +~*A*=2<sup>*n*</sup>-1, we can say that -*A*=~*A*+1 or equivalently ~*A*=-*A*-1

This is true for any number, positive or negative. And ~512=-512-1=-513

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first negate and add 1.

```
-x = ~x + 1
```

consequently

```
~x= -x -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val = 512
print (~val)
```

output:

-513

> **~ bitwise complement**
>
> Sets the 1 bits to 0 and 1 to 0.

[image]

For example ~2 would result in -3.

This is because the bit-wise operator would first represent the number in sign and magnitude which is 0000 0010 (8 bit operator) where the MSB is the sign bit.

Then later it would take the negative number of 2 which is -2.

-2 is represented as 1000 0010 (8 bit operator) in sign and magnitude.

Later it adds a 1 to the LSB (1000 0010 + 1) which gives you 1000 0011.

Which is -3.

**Otherwise:**

> ```
> y = -(512+1)
> print (y)
> ```

output:

-513